# thunkAPI.getState is not a function: Error with reduxtoolkit and jest

Tags: typescript, redux, jestjs, redux-toolkit

I'm using createAsyncThunk and writing a test for it with jest/ReduxToolkit/TypeScript.

This is my slice.

```
export const getUsers = createAsyncThunk<object[], undefined, { state: RootState }>(
  'user/getUsers',
  (_: undefined, thunkAPI) => {
    const { users } = thunkAPI.getState().user;
    if (!users) {
      // fetch users
    }
    return users;
  },
);

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: {
    users: [],
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(getUsers.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.users = action.payload;
      });
  },
});

export default userSlice;
```

This is my test.

```
let store: EnhancedStore;

beforeEach(() => {
  store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
      user: userSlice.reducer,
    },
  });
});

describe('userSlice', () => {
  test('getUsers success', async () => {
    const state = await getUsers();
    const result = await state(store.dispatch, store.getState(), undefined);
    console.log(result)
    expect(result.type).toBe('user/getUsers/fulfilled');
    expect(result.meta.requestStatus).toBe('fulfilled');
  });
});
```

When I run the test, I get the error and the log outputs:

> {
> type: 'user/getUsers/rejected',
> payload: undefined,
> meta: {
> arg: undefined,
> requestId: '***************',
> rejectedWithValue: false,
> requestStatus: 'rejected',
> aborted: false,
> condition: false
> },
> error: {
> name: 'TypeError',
> message: 'thunkAPI.getState is not a function',
> stack: 'TypeError: thunkAPI.getState is not a function\n' + // omitted
> }
> }

So I understand the error message `TypeError: thunkAPI.getState is not a function` states the `thunkAPI.getState()` in the slice causes the error but it doesn't cause any error while running it with a web browser.

Does anyone have an idea? Thank you.

##### Versions

- react-redux v7.2.5
- reduxjs/toolkit v1.6.1
- jest v27.0.6
- ts-jest v27.0.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inferred TS type of `state` variable is:

```
const state: (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<any, unknown, AnyAction>, getState: () => any, extra: unknown) => Promise<PayloadAction<object[], string, {
    arg: undefined;
    requestId: string;
    requestStatus: "fulfilled";
}, never> | PayloadAction<...>> & {
    ...;
}
```

You should pass the `store.getState` rather than `store.getState()` to `state`. So it should be:

```
const result = await state(store.dispatch, store.getState, undefined);
```

NOT:

```
const result = await state(store.dispatch, store.getState(), undefined);
```

Answer (score 2):

You really should dispatch that and let the store call that thunk and not do it yourself:

```js
    const result = await dispatch(getUsers())
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I thought for the testing environment, I need to call the thunk with the store like the code example to test store changes.

Comment: No, the store that you will `dispatch` to will do exactly that call internally.

Comment: Like `const result = await store.dispatch(getUsers());`? This causes a type mismatch error so I avoided this one. But it works fine with reducers, not thunks.

Comment: It works fine with thunks. And thunks should always be dispatched, never called, regardless of where you are.
If you have TypeScript errors with dispatch that probably means that you have Redux 4.0.5 and 4.1.1 both installed in your node_modules which causes weird type problems.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the problem is the type mismatch. I had to specify the type of `dispatch`.

First export AppDispatch like the official documentation says.

```
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

And when you call dispatch, you need to explicitly　type　dispatch in your test.

```
let store: EnhancedStore;
let dispatch: AppDispatch;

beforeEach(() => {
store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
      // Add your reducers
    },
  });
  dispatch = store.dispatch;
});
```

And after that, you can call dispatch both thunks and actions. Just write `dispatch([thunk/action])` and you are good to go.